# (Java) How do I make a program retry something until it gets a specific value?

Tags: java, string, treeview

I'm making a program that can filter information (`branches`) in a `TreeView` based on the name of the `branches`.

I made a method to get a random `branch` from `TreeView` menu as long as the `branch` contains the `String` `"=s="`.
Here is the method:

```
public TreeItem<String> randomBranch(TreeItem<String> parent){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int listNum = parent.getChildren().size();

    int num = rand.nextInt(listNum) + 0;

    TreeItem<String> getIT = parent.getChildren().get(num);

    if(getIT.toString().contains("=s=")){
        return getIT
    }
    else{
    (Missing_code_here)
    }
}
```

I don't know what to put in the `else`. But I want it so it re-tries until it finds a `branch` that contains `"=s="`.
How do I do this?

Comment: You're only seeking a random branch one level deep, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, all you need is a simple loop.

```
public TreeItem<String> randomBranch(TreeItem<String> parent) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int listNum = parent.getChildren().size();

    int num;
    TreeItem<String> getIT;

    do {
        num = rand.nextInt(listNum) + 0;
        getIT = parent.getChildren().get(num);
    } while (!getIT.toString().contains("=s="));

    return getIt;
}
```

Of course, if the structure doesn't contain an item with the string `"=s="`, you'll be stuck with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need a loop - below is one way to do it. You may enhance it further to exit the loop after 'n' number of tries etc (n could be = listNum), otherwise it will get stuck in a loop if none of your data contains "=s=".

```
 TreeItem<String> result;
 boolean branchFound=false;

 while(!branchFound){
    int num = rand.nextInt(listNum) + 0;

     TreeItem<String> getIT = parent.getChildren().get(num);

     if(getIT.toString().contains("=s=")){
       result = getIT;
       branchFound =true;
    }       
}
```